# Validating input using regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to validate text box, it should accept only alphabets (capital or small), digits, and `.,?-_`.
It should not accept any other values.
It should not accept same value like `......` or `,,,,,` or `-----` or `????` or `_____`.
It should not accept values like `,._` it should contain either alphabet or digit with this, like eg `_.ab.?`.

Comment: Can you describe what the field represents? That would make it clearer what logic you are trying to capture.

Comment: Please show some specific code you've tried.  If you don't know where to start, google "javascript regex tutorial"

Comment: Related to you question, I hope you know that you in any case also MUST do the same input validation server side as well, no matter how perfect your javascript is doing it.

Answer (score 2):

So you want the string to contain at least one (ASCII) alphanumeric character and at least two different characters?

Try

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z0-9])(?!(.)\1*$)[A-Z0-9.,?_-]*$/i
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                # start of string
(?=.*[A-Z0-9])   # assert that there is at least one of A-Z or 0-9
(?!(.)\1*$)      # assert that the string doesn't consist of identical characters
[A-Z0-9.,?_-]*   # match only allowed characters
$                # until the end of the string
```